# htaccess - match ANY URL (in the same domain)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite URLs using .htaccess

I want mod_rewrite to match ANY URL and then rewrite it to something else. By ANY URL, I mean URLs inside the same domain.

Examples of ANY URL:

- example.com
- example.com/index.php
- example.com/images/background.png
- example.com/foo/bar/
- example.com/?page=10
- example.com/some/some/url/inside/this/domain/
- example.com/foo/?bar=22

I want the regexp to match ANY of the above URLs. What is the regexp that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
>   ^(example.com|www.example.com)
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>   /some-target-page.html[L,QSA]

^ means start and $ means end