# htaccess select any url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all urls trying to access files in a folder to a common php page where I log the file being download and also checks whether the user is logged in or not, I'm trying the following way, but I'm not getting required result

Method 1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewrteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?file=$1
```

Method 2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?file=$1
```

My index.php

```
<php echo 'file - ' . $_REQUEST['file']; ?>
```

When I'm using the URL as `http://localhost/next/files/Cool`
Output Method 1 :

```
file - index.php
```

Output Method 2 :

```
file - Cool
```

Could you please tell me what is the wrong I'm doing in Method-1.
I could use Method-2 but the fileName could be anything [could contain all characters], so I need a regular expression which covers all [like in Method-1]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, dint work.
But this worked: [L,QSA]  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027388/htaccess-match-any-url-in-the-same-domain

Could you please let me know what are these?

Comment: here you can find all flags explained http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Method 1 is that you create an endless redirection.
Since all files are redirected to index.php, index.php itself is also redirected to index.php, and so on.

You have to explicitly exclude index.php from the redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?file=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your first rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# forward requests to index.php as a query parameter
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And inside your index.php read `file` query parameter as:

```
echo 'file - ' . $_GET['file'];
```

Comment: This will obviously not work, since the rewrite should specifically rewrite *existing* files to index.php, too.

Comment: Thanks, small issue what is the fileName contains space. Say picture (1).jpg then it is matching only picture (leaving (1).jpg) - any suggestions here.

Comment: @apfelbox Pls start reading about mod_rewrite, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will skip rewrite rule for any physical file. I had comments in my answer too but probably you didn't pay attention to them.

Comment: @user237865: If you click the link or type in browser `http://localhost/picture (1).jpg` it will automatically become `http://localhost/picture%20(1).jpg`. And then in this case if you do `$_GET['file']` in your code you will get `picture (1).jpg`

Comment: @anubhava I already know about mod_rewrite. The request of the question owner was - as far as I understood - that he wanted to rewrite URLs to **existing** files, to make some preprocessing in PHP. This is **not** possible in your solution, see my comment above.